# If $a$ in $S$ is a zero-divisor what is the quotient $\frac{a}{b}$ equal to? What about the quotient $\frac{0}{0}$?

Tags: commutative-algebra, equivalence-relations, localization

Let $R$ be a ring and let $S$ be a submonoid of $R$. The localization $R_S$ consists of the equivalence classes (fractions) $\frac{a}{b}$ such that $a\in{R}$, $b\in{S}$ defined by the relation $\sim$ in $R_S$ such that $(a,b)\sim(c,d)$ if and only if there exists an element $s\in{S}$ such that $s(ad-bc)=0$.

It is proved that $R_S$ is zero if and only if $S$ contains zero.

I wonder to know if $a$ in $S$ is a zero-divisor what is the quotient $\frac{a}{b}$ equal to?

I think that since $a$ is a zero-divisor in $S$ then there exists $s\in{S}$ such that $as=0$. Hence $\frac{a}{b}=\frac{as}{bs}=0$.

Moreover, what can we say about the quotient $\frac{0}{0}$? If $\frac{0}{0}=\frac{a}{b}$ then there exists $s\in{S}$ such that $s(0b-0a)=s0=0$. Does it follow that $\frac{0}{0}$ gives all $R_S$?

Would you help me, please? Thank you in advance.

Comment: If $0\in S$, then $R_S$ is the zero ring, yes, because $\frac00$ is equivalent to any other fraction, as you have seen. The map $R\to R_S$ given by $x\mapsto \frac x1$ is injective iff $S$ contains no zero divisors.

Comment: @Arthur Thank you for your comment! So, the quotient 0/0 gives the zero ring since $0/0=0/1=1/1$. What can we say about the quotient $a/0$? I think that $a/0=0/1=1/1$. So, can we say that the quotient $a/0$ makes sense if and only if $R_S$ is the zero ring?

Comment: Why not consider an example? Let $R=\Bbb Z/6\Bbb Z$ and $S=\{1,3\}$. Is $1/3$ equal to zero in $S^{-1}R$?

Comment: If $R_S$ is not the zero ring, then $0\notin S$, and therefore $\frac a0$ doesn't make sense, since $0$ is not a permitted denominator. (Remember, $S$ defines what denominators are permitted, and what factors you're allowed to expand and simplify fractions by.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $0\in S$, then $R_S$ is the zero ring, yes, because $\frac00$ is equivalent to any other fraction, as you have seen, so the ring necessarily contains only one element.

The map $R\to R_S$ given by $x\mapsto \frac x1$ is injective iff $S$ contains no zero divisors. If $a\in S$ is a zero divisor, and $b\in R$ is such that $ab=0$, then $\frac b1=\frac01$. But if $b\notin S$, $R_S$ is not necessarily the zero ring.

Your $\frac ab$ doesn't make sense because we don't know that $b\in S$.

I think I covered most of it. Let me know if there is something I missed.

Finally, the $s(ad-bc)=0$ requirement I like to think of as "you can expand both fractions so that numerators are equal and denominators are equal". It's a lot more intuitive in my opinion. Just remember that you're only allowed to use elements of $S$ when expanding.

Comment: Thank you! So, if $a$ is a zero-divisor in $S$,i.e., there exists $s\in{S}$ such that $as=0$, then the fraction $a/b=as/bs=0/bs=0$. If the set of zero-divisors of $a$ are in $R-S$ then the quotient $a/b$ does not make sense since $as=0$ for $s\in{R-S}$ but we don't know whether $bs\in{S}$?

Comment: If $a,s$ are both in $S$ and $as=0$, then $0\in S$, so $R_S$ is the zero ring as per the comments above. If $a\notin S, s\in S$ such that $as=0$, and $b\in S$, then $\frac ab$ makes sense, and is equal to $\frac{as}{bs}=\frac0{bs}=0$. If $S$ is contains no zero divisors (including if it is the complement of the set of zero divisors), then everything is nice and the only fractions that are zero are the ones that actually have zero in the numerator.