# Localization with respect to a multiplicative set containing zero divisors

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, localization

From what I understand, the localization of a ring $R$ with a multiplicative set $S$ is a construction of a bigger ring $R^*$ such that $R$ is a subring in this bigger ring and every element in $S$ is a unit.

Furthermore, we want that if we have any ring homomorphism $\phi$ from $R$ to another ring $T$ such that $\phi(d)$ is a unit ($d \in R$) and $\phi(1) = 1$, we also want that the construction of $R^*$ satisfies the universal property. So there is a unique homomorphism $\pi$ from $R^*$ to $T$ such that $\phi = \pi \circ \rho$ where $\rho$ is the homomorphism from $R$ to $R^*$.

Now my question is (sorry it takes so long to get to the point) what if I had that my multiplicative set contains two zero divisors $d$ and $d'$ where $dd'=0$? How can any ring homomorphism map any zero divisors to a unit element in $T$?

Since $\phi(dd') = \phi(0) = 0 =  \phi(d)\phi(d')$.

So $\phi(d)$ and $\phi(d')$ are zero divisors, hence they cannot be units.

Where did my reasoning go wrong?

Comment: You can find there what would you like.https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2385961/if-a-in-s-is-a-zero-divisor-what-is-the-quotient-fracab-equal-to-wha?rq=1

Comment: Basically, if $S$ contains a zero divisor then the localization is the zero ring (that is because as you said you cannot map a zero divisor to a unit unless zero is a unit which only happens in the zero ring). It is not true that the localization is always a bigger ring, sometimes is is smaller.

Comment: @Levent Your first claim is wrong. For $R=\mathbb Z_6$ consider $S=\{\hat 1,\hat 2,\hat 4\}$. Prove that $S^{-1}R\simeq\mathbb Z_3$.

Comment: You are definitely right. The correct argument is if $S$ contains a zero divisor $x$ and if $x\cdot y=0$, then the image of $y$ must be zero (that's because the images of $x$ and $y$ still give $0$ when multiplied, since the image of $x$ is a unit the image of $y$ must be $0$). Hence the localization sometimes result in smaller rings.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I now realize two things: 1. It is not the case that localization is a bigger ring into which R imbedds, this is only true for rings of fractions, namely S that does not contain any zero divisor. Also 2, If it is the case that we have S contains two associating zero divisor, since S is a multiplicative set, 0 must be in S, but then 0 by definition of localization is a unit in the localization, hence the localization has to be the zero ring. is that correct?

Comment: A localization is the zero ring iff the localizing set $S$ contains a nilpotent. As demonstrated by @user26857, zero divisors can ruin injectivity, but even a zero divisor in $S$ cannot annihilate the unit by iterated action unless it is nilpotent.

Comment: Another example I found illuminating: $\{ (1, 1), (1, 0) \}^{-1}\mathbb{Z}^2 \cong \mathbb{Z}$

Answer (score 4):

Your reasoning is not wrong. You have shown localization is not injective in general.

Suppose you're localizing at a subset $S\subset A$. You have shown that if $s_1,s_2\in S$ satisfy $s_1s_2=0$ then $0=1\in A[S^{-1}]$. If your $S$ is multiplicatively closed, then your assumptions means $0\in S$, so it may be unsurprising that inverting zero kills the ring.

It can also happen that $s\in S$ is a zero divisor in $A$, but that $s$ does not kill any elements in $S$. In this case, the localization can fail to be injective without being zero. A simple example was given in the comments by user26857: if you localize the quotient ring $\mathbb Z/6\mathbb Z$ at the zero divisor $\hat 2$ you get the field $\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z$.